# Обновление Google Map каждой секунды

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api

Есть база даных с координатами автомобиля. База обновляется каждую секунду. Потому мне нужно автоматически обновлять Google Map каждую секунду. Искал в документации, но не нашел как ето сделать.

```js
setTimeout(function () { location.reload(true); }, 1000);
 
var map;
function initialize() {
 var mapOptions = {
           center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.842547, 24.026544),
           zoom: 7,
           mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 };
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
             mapOptions);
        
   //      google.maps.event.addListener(map,"titlesLoade",function(){setInterval(redrawMap,1000);})
     
         $.ajax({
                 url:'http://localhost:8087/api/getDataForSec',
                 dataType: "json", 
                 success: function(data){
                  var markers=[];
                     $.each(data, function(key, data) {
                      console.log(data.coordinatew, data.coordinatee);
                         var mylatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.coordinatew, data.coordinatee);
                         // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
                         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                           position: mylatlng,
                           title:data.car_name
                         });
                         markers.push(marker);
                         marker.setMap(map);
                     });


  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
             {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
     
                 }
             });

       }
       google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

```css
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 80%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
#map_canvas { height: 100% }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD6wbSA91NaZlfmGKyV_TaFxI6Dpxr3BdM&sensor=true">
  </script> 
  <script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js">
  </script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script> 
 </head>
 <body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Setinterval](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval) - Запускает выполнение функции, регулярно повторяет её через указанный интервал времени.

```js
function func() {
   //marker.setPosition(); <- Google map marker position
   console.log( 'Update' );
}
setInterval(func, 1000);
```

Comment: А где именно в коде ее нужно вставить, я просто только знакомлюсь с JavaScript

Comment: да,я прикрепил код

Comment: @mi.mo вы можете вызывать функцию initialize() в setinterval()  или просто ajax запрашивать через setinterval. То есть либо ajax обернуть либо вызывать функцию. Писать в вмето  console.log( 'Update' );

Comment: А можно как-то Ajax обернуть в функцию?

Comment: @mi.mo просто вставьте аjax за место console.log( 'Update' ); с ответа